# Validating numeric values using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code. It works fine for blank fields, but it doesn't catch the other numeric exceptions. What am I doing wrong?

```
function validateForm() {
    var a = document.forms["Form"]["percentage"].value;
    var b = document.forms["Form"]["minutes"].value;
    if (a == null || b == null || a == "" || b == "") {
        alert("Please Fill All Required Field");
        return false;
    } else if (isNan(a) == true || isNan(b) == true) {
        alert("Please enter valid numeric values");
        return false;
    } else if (parseInt(a) > 100) {
        alert("Percentage can't exceed 100");
        return false;
    } else if (parseInt(b) < 0 || parseInt(a) < 0) {
        alert("Values can't be negative");
        return false;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
else if((isNan(a)==true) ||(isNan(b)==true)){
```

to this:

```
else if (isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)) {
```

as the function is named [`#isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN). Using `== true` in conditionals is quite redundant, so I removed them.

I have also made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y2Luad4k/) for you. It contains the fixed code, and it is working well.

Comment: Redundant, yes; but tangential to the problem itself.